# Where does the new Microsoft Edge (Chromium) install extensions on my Windows machine?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge, chromium

Where on my file system can I locate the extensions I have installed for the new Microsoft Edge?  I'm looking at developing some extensions but I would love to know where Edge keeps them all.

Comment: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions - it uses the standard Windows directory structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, We could visit the installed extensions from the following folder:

```
 %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

or

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

[**Note**] The installed extension folder name might be is not the extension name, it is the extension **ID** property (Click the "Details" link in the installed Extensions (edge://extensions/)).

For example: Using the **New Microsoft Edge** install Edge Translate extension, the extension folder name is "bfdogplmndidlpjfhoijckpakkdjkkil".

[image]

[**Note**] If you are using **Microsoft Edge Beta/Dev/Can** version, the extensions folder path should be based on the Edge version, like this:

```
 %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge Beta\User Data\Default\Extensions
```

[**Note**] If you add multiple profiles, we could visit the extension from the related Profile folder, like this (the {number} starting from 1):

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Profile {number}\Extensions
```

Comment: Shouldn't the path change based on the profile used? I don't know about Edge but in Chromium `Default` might be `User n` where `n` is a number based on how many profiles have been created. Also it's better user `%userprofile%` env. variable instead as Windows could have been installed on a different drive

Comment: @Asesh, Thanks for reminding me about that, I have modified my reply.

Comment: It's still not correct, `%userprofile%` is an env. variable, so it should be something like this: `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Extensions`. Also that path is for default profile. If you create another profile in Chromium, it's path will be: `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Chromium\User Data\User (n)\Extensions` where `(n)` is a number starting from 1, instead of `Default` folder, which is only for the default profile. Not sure if Edge supports multiple profiles.

Comment: @Asesh, you are right, the new Microsoft Edge also support multiple profiles, if have multiple profiles, we should find the extension from the related profile folder. Thanks for reminding me about that.

Answer (score 0):

%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Profile 1\Extensions

%userprofile% = C:\Users\user name

Notice that profile 1 is the default profile but it could be changed from profile settings.

so if you didn't find profile 1, look for possible profile name you have changed to.